# In a square matrix is R(A) equals C(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

[image: QUESTION]
[image: ANSWER]

This is from Professor Gilbert Strang's Introduction to linear algebra.

Here's what I think. If we look at this matrix,

\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 5 & 7\\
3 & 10&13
\end{matrix}

It's row space has basis [1 2 3],[0 1 4] and the column space has a basis [1 2 3], [0 1 1].
So clearly these basis span two different subspaces in R³.So the row space and column space aren't the same. So the statement is False.

But is the reason given in the text correct?
From what I have learnt the rank of both C(A) and R(A) have to be the same. This means they have the same dimension. Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason given in the solution is a bit weird. It could be that they forgot the $m=n$ condition, and are saying that "the row space and column space are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ respectively, which in general may not have the same dimension, in which case the row space and column space cannot be equal." But this is irrelevant in the case $m=n$. Further, you are correct that in general the row space and column space have the same dimension (even in non-square matrices). Your answer is a correct counterexample for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the statement is actually false in both parts. For square matrices with random entries in $\mathbb R$ the determinant is non-zero almost surely, meaning that they are non-singular and that their row and column spaces are all $\mathbb R^n$. The dimensions of row and column spaces are the row rank and column rank, well-known to be equal. Finally, a smaller counterexample is the $2×2$ matrix with zeros everywhere but a $1$ in the top-right corner.